# How can I add a "Recurring" filter to core "Repeat contribution" report?

Tags: civireport, reports, custom-reports

I need a particular type of report which I could not find in core or extended reports.

So I thought of modifying the core report PHP and place it in custom PHP directory. I have manage to add "payment instrument" filter to this particular report.

```
        'payment_instrument_id' => array(
        'title' => ts('Payment Instrument'),
        'type' => CRM_Utils_Type::T_INT,
        'operatorType' => CRM_Report_Form::OP_MULTISELECT,
        'options' => CRM_Contribute_PseudoConstant::paymentInstrument(),
      ),
```

However, I need to add another item to the group to filter the result limited to recurring contribution. It could be a checkbox or a Yes/No. Can anyone suggest how can I add it please? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Over-riding core file would be last thing we should do unless there are no other option, since you need to port the file in each incremental upgrade.

Instead I would do one of the below

1. To add filtes, fields etc to report i would implement [hook_civicrm_alterReportVar](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_alterReportVar/) via extension or module or plugin
2. If the requirement is too complex than i would create new report file extending Repeat Contribution report(see [example](https://gist.github.com/pradpnayak/f9589797dca332ca6e87a2b8fc3af64e))